# phpmyadmin event executed twice

Tags: database, events, phpmyadmin, task

I have a problem with phpmyadmin

I run a task every day at 00:10.

This task adds clocking times from the previous day to obtain the day's total in another table.

Only in rare cases (less than once a month) the task is executed twice on the same day and 2 identical lines are created. Which creates a problem for the weekly total or monthly total. Do you have any idea why?

Here is a [picture of the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvJTt.png)

thanks a lot for your help,

Kevin.